# SPI Slave Programming for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-due, spi

In my application Arduino Due is configured as master and instead of the actual slave device I am making use of Arduino Uno as Slave.I will share the Master code which I have worked out. Can Anyone please help me with respect to slave code of Arduino Uno to display the data in serial monitor at slave side. Any Help With respect to this aspect will be greatly greatly appreciated.

```
#include <SPI.h>

SPISettings mySettting(125000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);
const uint8_t ss = 10;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ss, OUTPUT);

  SPI.begin();

  digitalWrite(ss, LOW);
  SPI.beginTransaction(mySettting);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  SPI.transfer(0x25);
  SPI.transfer(0x1C);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(ss, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
}
```

---

Thanks for the reply.
Referring to the code attached below at the slave side as you have mentioned that HEX to be displayed in serial monitor window, Do I need to add the HEX at the master side I mean Do I need to load the Hexadecimal data (0x00251C) into HEX buffer??

Thanks in Advance

```
#include <SPI.h>

SPISettings mySettting(125000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);
const uint8_t ss = 10;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ss, OUTPUT);

  SPI.begin();

  digitalWrite(ss, LOW);
  SPI.beginTransaction(mySettting);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  SPI.transfer(0x25);
  SPI.transfer(0x1C);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(ss, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information if required.

Answer (score 4):

SPI.h library by default only support Master mode, the `SPI.begin()` will automatically set slave select (ss) pin to HIGH whether you have `pinMode(ss, OUTPUT)` in your setup() code or not and set the Arduino as an SPI master. This can be see on SPI library [source code](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/libraries/SPI/src/SPI.cpp#L36-L51).

As the SPI library does not contain the functionality for slave mode, in order to use Arduino as a Slave, you will need to do some customised setup, mainly on 1) setting MISO as OUTPUT for slave to send data; 2) enable slave mode by setting the SPCR register; 3) enable interrupt when data is received. Here is an example for an SPI slave on Arduino.

```
#include<SPI.h>

volatile boolean received;
volatile byte receivedData;

ISR (SPI_STC_vect)        //Inerrrput routine function 
{
  receivedData = SPDR;   // Get the received data from SPDR register
  received = true;       // Sets received as True 
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(MISO,OUTPUT);   //Sets MISO as OUTPUT
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);       //Turn on SPI in Slave Mode
  received = false;
  SPI.attachInterrupt();  //Activate SPI Interuupt 
}


void loop()
{ 
  if(received) {                        
    SPDR = receivedData;    // send back the received data, this is not necessary, only for demo purpose
    received = false;
    Serial.print(receivedData, HEX);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now the data is transferred on MOSI line at Master end. I would like to monitor that MISO pin incoming data in slave side. In the above code which you have posted once I define MISO pin and in place of HEX  in the last line of the code I don't want the HEX value to be written in the last line.  I just want to display the HEX value written at MASTER side. I don't want to include it at slave side.